# Reagent does not register atom watch

Tags: clojure, reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I have simple newcomer's [luminus](http://www.luminusweb.net/) with [reagent](http://reagent-project.github.io/) application.
I defined some component definition:

```
(def md-vals (atom nil))

(defn markdown [url]
  (GET
    (str js/context url)
    {:handler
     (fn [response]
       (swap! md-vals assoc url response)
       (js/alert (str "loaded\n" (subs response 1 100))))})
  (fn [] [:p (get @md-vals url "loading...")]))
```

It's usage as page component:

```
(defn docs [] [markdown "/md/docs.md"])
```

And finally page binding:

```
(defn init! []
  ...
  (render-component (docs)  (.getElementById js.document "docs")))
```

All works fine except atom state switch notification. At the time of successfull resource get i'm seeing `alert` message as supposed, but corresponding area of page does not switching.

Chrome debugger shows that at the moment of atom switch atom's `watches` property is empty (`null`), so no notification is fired.

What could probably be wrong in my approach?

Comment: Are you using `reagent.core/atom` or plain Clojure `atom`? Please post your namespace declaration.

Comment: @sbensu Thank you! It's of course built-in atom without reagent reference. Could you please describe this ambiguity in answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `reagent.core/atom` instead of regular Clojure `atom`. Add this to your namespace `:require`:

```clj
[reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]
```